# Rating Randomness of Electromagnetic Conductivity (EC) Data Collected?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, spatial-statistics

So we have electromagnetic conductivity (EC) data that we have been collecting over some forest ground which logs an EC value every couple of seconds.  We like to see the data have nice distinct patterns to it so when you add symbology to the data with Class Breaks you get are nice clear and distinct areas of varying EC.  Some times we get data that is much more random in natural and doesn't have the nice distinct zones and areas of EC but rather has more of just random values across the area we collected data (i.e. big swings in EC values across small areas in spatially).  I would like to find a way to statistically rate how random the data is.  If there are nice distinct zones, it should give a rating of cleaner data.  If the data is much more random without good distinct areas of EC and lack of more consistent changes across the field, then it would give a low rating of clean data and high randomness of data.  I know my terminology is bad here but is there something in ArcMap I could use to measure the randomness of the collected data?

Comment: For a bit of clarification - are you talking about the randomness of values themselves by location, or the randomness of the locations? Basically, are you looking for a way to find out whether the randomness of the values is, in fact, spatially explainable?

Comment: Andrew, basically how random the data is.  If values have large swings over a short distance, I would consider that highly random.  If the values are much more gradual even over longer distances (points further from each other) then I would consider the data not random at all.  Highly random data will tell us it's most likely bad data and not usable.  I don't care to know whether the randomness is spatially explainable.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Spatial Autocorrelation (Global Moran's I)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Spatial_Autocorrelation_Global_Moran_s_I/005p0000000n000000/) tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at the [Spatial Autocorrelation (Global Moran's I)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Spatial_Autocorrelation_Global_Moran_s_I/005p0000000n000000/) tool for one possible way to rate the randomness of your data. It looks at whether value occurrences are clustered or dispersed. Based on your question and comment, more clustered would be 'less random' and more dispersed would be 'more random'.

Comment: It's a little tough to know precisely what to consider pretty random data.  I seem to be getting values less than 0.50 for what looks visually random, and values above 0.70 where the data looks more clustered.  I'm always getting p-values of 0.0000 and very high z-values of often over 20.  Thanks for directing me to this.